# Will this eventually lead to a crash (wxpython)

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have over 300 questions/prompts that I plan to include in the program. The flow is pretty much like this:

**Create a window with the question.
Store answer in variable.
Create NEW window with question.
Store NEW answer.**

*this continues on for over 300 questions.*

---

I have 2 concerns:

---

1) Will this eventually lead to a crash since I'm creating so many windows

2) Everything works with this code if you select 'Yes' to the second question (A2) but it does not work if you select 'No'. Can you please see if you can find what's wrong with it?

---

```
import wx

a1 = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Strawberries', 'Watermelon',
     "Don't remember", 'None of the above']

a2 = ['No', 'Yes']

a4 = ['No', 'Yes']


class Fruit(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Fruit', size=(300,200))

        #create panel and button
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # B1 - create multiple choice list
        box = wx.MultiChoiceDialog(None, """

A1.    What kind of fruit did you buy at the store?""", 'Fruit', a1)
        if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            a_1 = box.GetSelections()


        print (a_1, '\n')

        # A2 - create single choice list
        box = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, """
A2.    Do you like eating fruit?
""", 'Fruit', a2)
        if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            a_2 = box.GetStringSelection()

        print (a_2, '\n')

        if a_2 == 'Yes':
            box = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "A3.    What kind of fruit is your favorite? ", "Fruit", "")
        if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            a_3 = box.GetValue()

        print (a_3, '\n')


        box = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, """
A4.    Did you eat the fruit that you bought?
""", 'Fruit', a4)
        if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            a_4 = box.GetStringSelection()

        print (a_4, '\n')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holy Cow.  You're not really chaining the dialogs like that are you?  To try to answer your questions:

1. Will this eventually lead to a crash:  This snippet of code should fail at the first `print` following someone clicking No.  See bullet point #2.  There's a lot missing here, I don't see any error handling, no `__main__`, missing an `App()` etc.  Because you're repeatedly reassigning the value of `box` I don't think you're likely to encounter memory issues, but those are the least of your concerns at this stage.
2. Everything works if you click Yes, but fails if you click No:  That's coming from this `box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK`.  You're only creating the variables `a_#` if you get the OK value from your Dialog.  You could do this instead:

   `a_1 = box.getSelections() if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK else None`

Here you'd substitute in some meaningful value for `None`..  Note that this uses the Python Ternary Syntax, which was introduced in 2.5 or 2.6.  It would not work with 2.4.

All that said, what you probably want to create is a Wizard.  They are "typically used to decompose a complex dialog into several simple steps".  There's a tutorial available here at [wxWidgets](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxWizard) that might shed some light.  Once you've looked at that a little bit you should investigate sizers, as it appears you're using multiline strings to create white spaces(?).

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the indentation so that when someone selects "No" it proceeds with the other questions. But I'm confused about what the __main__ function  and App() function are for.

Comment: @Jerry - `__main__` refers a line like `if __name__ == '__main__':`, typically toward the bottom of a module.  It's the common Python idiom for creating code that executes when the script is run (python myApp.py) but not when the script is imported (import myApp).

Comment: @Jerry - As for the call to `App()` - this is required for any wx program.  You may be calling wx.PySimpleApp() somewhere instead, is a possibility.

Comment: @ g.d.d.c - I see, I actually do have a call to wx.PySimpleApp(). Also, I understand now about __main__. Thank you for your help.